# Scan a JSON string in the View function in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: json, asp.net-core-3.1

I pass a string to my view in this code snippet:

```
List<List<Book>> data = getData();
string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<List<Book>>>(data);
ViewData["Orders"] = jsonData;
```

`getData()` returns a list of list of a class, so `jsonData` looks something like this after the JSON Serialize:

```
[
    [ "title": "Some title", "price": 12.00 ], 
    [ "title": "Some other title", "price": 23.00 ]
]
```

Now, how in the world do I parse this in my view? I can do something like this

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Books";
}

<p>@ViewData["Orders"]</p>
```

And print out the content, but there do not seem like any way to parse the string to a JSON object so I can present it. I have tried to instead pass the `data` variable to the `ViewData` but then I can not parse it since it can not find the `Book` class, so I am so confused...

Comment: Why on earth do you want to serialize and then de-serialize it on the way to your view? just pass `data` to the view and use it there?

Comment: @MarianTheisen Well I cant. If so I will have a `List<List<Book>>` type but the stupid thing do not recognize the `Book` class. So I have tried to make a model but no. Seems like there is something major I have missed. If I were using Flask I would just pass it the data and parse it any way I want, it do not seem to work that way here for some reason, so thought JSON would work better, but no.

Comment: Are the views in another assembly that needs a reference to the assembly where the Book class lives?

Comment: @MarianTheisen I have no ideea, what do you need in order to know if they are? Only assembly reference I have now is to the tests, but that should not create a conflict

Comment: okay seems like you probably only have 1 assembly/project, maybe you are just missing the `using WhereeverItsLocated.Book` directive?